# Use placeholder in TCPDF

Tags: php, replace, tcpdf, placeholder

I run some complex calculations for a creditnote and the first page is a summary of the overall amount. 
What i do not want to do is run through all provisions to calculate the summary and afterwards run through them again to render the detail view.
So is it possible to define custom placeholders that i can replace after i added the detail view?
Or do you know another way to achieve the wanted result without running the calculations twice?

Edit:

This is how i render the detail view:

```
        foreach($this->_creditNote->provisioningClient->customers as $customer)
        {
            $provisions = $customer->getProvisionsByBillingPeriodSum($this->_creditNote->billingPeriod);
            if((count($provisions) >= 3 && $this->y > 230) || $this->y > 250)
            {
                $this->AddPage();
                $this->SetFillColor(240);
                $this->SetDrawColor(0);
                $this->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 10);
                $this->Cell(140, 6, 'Die Provisionen im Einzelnen', 'TB', 0, 'L', 1);
                $this->Cell(30, 6, "Beträge", 'TB', 1, 'R', 1);
                $this->SetXY(25, $this->y-11.5);
                $this->SetTextColor(170,170,170);
                $this->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 7);
                $this->Cell(175, 6, 'Seite ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . ' von ' . $this->getAliasNbPages(), '', 2, 'R');
                $this->SetY($this->y+6);
                $this->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 9);
                $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
            }
            if(count($provisions) > 0)
            {
                $customerData = array();
                $this->SetXY(20, $this->y+1);
                $this->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 10);
                $this->Cell(140, 0, $customer->contact->name . " (" . $customer->customerNumber . ")");
                //add customer
                $amount = 0;
                $rows = array();
                foreach($provisions as $provision)
                {
                    $text = $provision->description;
                    $description = "";
                    if($provision->period != "onetime")
                    {
                        if($provision->isPartial($this->_creditNote->billingPeriod))
                            $text .= ", anteilig";
                        $description = $provision->periodName . ", " . $provision->getRuntime($this->_creditNote->billingPeriod);
                    }
                    if($description == "")
                        $description = null;
                    $temp = array($text, $provision->isPartial($this->_creditNote->billingPeriod) ? round($provision->getPartialAmount($this->_creditNote->billingPeriod)/100, 2) : $provision->amount / 100, $description);
                    $amount += $temp[1];
                    $rows[] = $temp;
                }
                $this->Cell(30, 0, number_format($amount, 2, ",", ".") . " €", 0, 1, 'R');
                foreach($rows as $row)
                {
                    $this->SetXY(23, $this->y+1);
                    $this->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 8);
                    $this->Cell(137, 0, $row[0]);
                    $this->Cell(30, 0, number_format($row[1], 2, ",", ".") . " €", 0, 1, 'R');
                    if($row[2])
                    {
                        $this->SetXY(26, $this->y + 1);
                        $this->SetFont('Helvetica', 'I', 8);
                        $this->MultiCell(140, 0, $row[2], 0, 'L');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance,
Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a similar task some time ago and therefore know that it's bad to iterate multiple times.

I've created a class which will do a all the calculations at first. Let's call it 'payoff' class. This will iterate over all orders that came in since last month. It will then create informations for

- each singel order (remove tax/etc...)
- an overall view (how many items/overall tax amount/etc.)

So it could look like this

```
$payoffInfo=new Payoff($arrayWithOrderInfos);

// do creation of tcpdf object include header/footer/ ...
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->setPDFVersion('1.4');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(FALSE);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(TRUE);

// create first page and set 'overall' like this ...

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, "Overall amount ".$payoffInfo->getItemCount() , 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 12);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0,"Overall amount ".$payoffInfo->getOverallAmount() , 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->Ln();

// include more Overview Informations ...
// Iterate over all single orders ...

foreach($payoffInfo->getOrders() as $item){
    $html = "<p><ul>";
    $html .= "<li>Item ID: ".$item['order_id']."</li>";
    $html .= "<li>Item Price ".$item['price']."</li>";
    $html .= "<li>Item Clear Amount ".$item['price_without_tax']."</li>";
    $html .= "</ul></p>";
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 'L');
}
// Mark Items as billed or sth. else so we don't include them again next month
$payoffInfo->setItemsToStatus("billed"); 

$pdf->Output($yourDesiredLocation, 'F');
```

To reduce the the amount of time and to prevent generating pdf's while server has a high load I moved this to a 'task' (or anything else). This tasked is then called once a month (depending on what time period you need) by a cron job in the middle of the night.

This solution works fine for ~400k orders per month and possible could do a lot more.

If you want stylish pdf's that can be styled exactly as you want them to be, I would use some kind of LaTeX "Interface" today. Because it's much easier to style the whole content including header and footer.

Hope this can help you reflect about your task.

Comment: At the end i did it your way. I calculated the total and while looping through the provisions i stored them for later access while rendering. Thx a lot! 
Although it is really sad, that there is no way to use custom placeholders in tcpdf :(

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you current code look something like this:

```
// this will contain the computation for every orders
$orders_infos = array();

// you need $orders_infos to be already filled here, but it is done after
$total = 0;
foreach ($orders_infos as $info) {
  $total += $info['total'];
}
$html = "html for the overview page: ".$total; // $total is wrong !
$pdf->writeHTML($html);

// compute infos for every order and display
foreach ($orders as $k => $order) {
  $orders_infos[$k] = compute_order_infos();
  $html = "html for this order page ".$orders_infos[$k]['total'];
  $pdf->writeHTML($html);
}
```

And your problem is that the total in the overview page is incorrect, because you run the calculation afterwards. The simple way to change it is to run all calculations and only then generate the resulting PDF, but you said you didn't want that for some reason.

The next best way to achieve what you want is to cheat a little and keep track of a list of commands to run as [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) and then run them at the end, this way you keep most of your current code organisation but still do all the displaying afterwards;

```
$commands = array();

// this will contain the computation for every orders
$orders_infos = array();

// you need $orders_infos to be already filled here, but it is done after
$total = 0;
$commands[] = function($pdf, $orders_infos) {
  foreach ($orders_infos as $info) {
    $total += $info['total'];
  }
  $html = "html for the overview page: ".$total;
  $pdf->writeHTML($html);
};

// compute infos for every order and display
foreach ($orders as $k => $order) {
  $orders_infos[$k] = compute_order_infos();
  $commands[] = function($pdf, $orders_infos) use ($k) {
    $html = "html for this order page ".$orders_infos[$k]['total'];
    $pdf->writeHTML($html);
  };
}

// now run all the commands
foreach ($commands as $command) {
  $command($pdf, $orders_infos);
}
```

And all your PDF writing commands, including the overview, will be executed at the end, once every calculation has been done.

A similar but simpler example so you can have a better view of how that will work:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $arr[$i] = $i;
}
$funcs = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  $funcs[] = function($arr) use($k) {
    echo $arr[$k]."\n";
  };
}

foreach ($funcs as $func) {
  echo "func: ";
  $func($arr);
}
```

Displays:

```
$ php test.php
func: 0
func: 1
func: 2
func: 3
func: 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will paste some of my code in my question.
Every month i have to generate a few creditnotes for provisioningclients with sometimes a lot of advertized customers. So what i did not want to do was calculate the summary render it and afterwards run through all the provisions and render them in detail. So i thought i could use placeholders just like the aliasnbpages etc. I had the thought too to run through it and save all needed data in arrays to render them at the end but i thought there could be a more comfy way :D